# Help with prior selection

Tags: bayesian, prior

Say I have two samples of univariate data, both of equal size: $X_1, \ldots, X_n \overset{\text{iid}}{\sim} \text{Normal}\left(\mu_1, \sigma^2_1\right)$ and $Y_1, \ldots, Y_n \overset{\text{iid}}{\sim} \text{Normal}\left(\mu_2, \sigma^2_2\right)$. Does anyone have any good suggestions for a prior that has the following properties:

1. $p(\mu_1, \mu_2)$ is exchangeable, and
2. $p(\mu_1, \mu_2)$ is "heavy on the extreme parts of the ridges/axes".

Regarding (2), the goal is to incorporate prior knowledge that if $\mu_2$ is large, it's very unlikely that $\mu_1$ is also large, and vice versa. I can  imagine a bivariate normal density surface, centered at the origin, and wondering if there's a way you can press your thumb down on a quadrant, to squish down the density and push all the mass to the x and y axes.

Comment: Independent heavy-tailed distributions (eg. t with low df) will concentrate probability near the axes when values are large, but not when they're small. e.g. if you use R, try ` set.seed(514394); plot(rt(3000,2),rt(3000,2),pch=16,col=rgb(.3,.3,.3,.3))` and see.